# Display error message instead of throw exception in console (Flutter Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How to show the error message when the user enters the incorrect username and password? Can I display a message when there are multiple conditions in authenticating the user? The message should show on the screen instead of throwing the exception in the console.

**The exception I get in the console**
The exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., {code: user-not-found, additionalData: {}, message: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.}, null))

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

abstract class BaseAuth {
  Future<String> currentUser();
  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password);
  Future<String> createUser(String email, String password);
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }

  Future<String> createUser(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }


  Future<String> currentUser() async {
    User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return user != null ? user.uid : null;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple try catch would do the trick

```
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
try{
    UserCredential result = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
User user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
}on AuthException catch(error){
return Future.error(error);
  }
}
```

Now on how to handle the error in the UI assuming you know the basics :D

```
await signIn(email,password).then((onSuccess){
 //do something with data or not up to you
 }).catchError((err){
 print(err);
 });
```

**Hope it helps :)**

Comment: This error occurs. The name 'AuthException' isn't a type and can't be used in an on-catch clause.
Try correcting the name to match an existing class.dartnon_type_in_catch_clause.

Comment: try this
} catch(error){
return Future.error(error);
  }

Comment: cannot work....I still cant found a solution to this problem...